# How to horizontally shrink a background image while keeping height constant

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that is taller than my page, but I set it as the background for my wrapper. This has been pretty problematic for me, however. When I try to resize the window, there is a large amount of white space under the background image. This is because I have a set height for my wrapper,

```
.wrapper{
  top: 65px;
  background-image: url(img/iasite.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width:100%;
  height:7250px;
  }
```

If I try changing the height to 100%, there is no background image at all and the page is blank(there is no other content in my wrapper at this point). If I do not set a height, the same happens. When I do put content in and set the height to 100%, the background image only goes up until a certain point before the rest is cropped, and there will still be elements hanging outside of the image.I think I could resolve this problem if I could somehow set my wrapper height to the height of my background image so that when it is resized, the webpage would read the background Image height and readjust the wrapper as so. Is there a way to do this, or is there another way to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

> background-size : cover